# Spring Batch | Read Count = Filter + Write?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

When running Spring Batch application, i see at some places in `STEP_EXECUTION` table, that

```
  `Read Count > Filter + Write`?
```

Should not it be equal?

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily.  If an item was skipped for example, it would have been read, but not filtered or written.  For the record, the filter count is the count of times the `ItemProcessor` returned null which is different than an item being skipped due to a skippable exception being thrown.